# Is this sentence missing an article?

Tags: articles, definite-article

> Carly DuHain, the lead singer for local soulful, bluesy rock ‘n’ roll band Drop Dead Red, has a tattoo on her right arm of a pinup girl that says Drop Dead Red. ([source](https://www.sacbee.com/entertainment/music-news-reviews/article214278229.html))

I find the sentence strange without the definite article before "local souful, bluesy rock 'n' roll band". Shouldn't it be:

> Carly DuHain, the lead singer for **the** local soulful, bluesy rock ‘n’ roll band Drop Dead Red, has a tattoo on her right arm of a pinup girl that says Drop Dead Red.

I am trying to compare it with, say, these sentences:

> Bezos, the CEO of company Amazon, has a tattoo. (strange, ungrammatical)
>
> Bezos, the CEO of **the** company Amazon, has a tattoo. (grammatical)

Am I correct to think the original sentence is incorrect and missing an article?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is OK. Basically, you are describing a proper name which otherwise would not need any article.

> the lead singer for (local soulful, bluesy rock ‘n’ roll band) Drop Dead Red

So if you leave out such descriptor, then you get:

> the lead singer for Drop Dead Red

which clearly would not use any article.

But I think some people would use an article, based on proximity, where the thought process focuses on:

> **the** lead singer

by itself.

As for your second example, I don't think "of company Amazon" is normal phrasing. Just "of Amazon".

Either way, it depends on what your mind is keying on, "Amazon" (no article) or "the company (named Amazon)" (article).